# AngularJS State management ->load multiple states in one page

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

i am developing a site in AngularJs with ui-router. I have a situation where on button click i need to change and load three state into that page and the three looks like the image .Please help me how can i load multiple pages. in one page

[image]

Comment: Please write what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your router config like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state("state1", {
        url: "/url1",
        controller: "FirstController",
        views: {
            view1: { templateUrl: "templates/template1.html" },
            view2: { templateUrl: "templates/template2.html" },
            view3: { templateUrl: "templates/template3.html" }
        }
    }).state("state2", {
        url: "/url2",
        controller: "SecondController",
        views: {
            view1: { templateUrl: "templates/template4.html" },
            view2: { templateUrl: "templates/template5.html" },
            view3: { templateUrl: "templates/template6.html" }
    }).state("state3", {
        url: "/url3",
        views: {
            view1: { 
                templateUrl: "templates/template7.html",
                controller: "ThirdController" 
            },
            view2: { 
                templateUrl: "templates/template8.html",
                controller: "FourthController" 
            },
            view3: { 
                templateUrl: "templates/template9.html",
                controller: "FifthController" 
            }
    });
```

So you need to provide information about every view in every state: templates that your views use, controllers, resolves, etc. Then you need to give names to your ui-view containers (in this example view1, view2, view3). That's how ui-router will know what templates and controllers it needs to use for every view  container.

And your view will look similar to this:

```
<section class="sidebar left">
    <div ui-view="view1"></div>
</section>

<section class="sidebar right login">
    <div ui-view="view2"></div>
</section>

<div ui-view="view3"></div>
```

Comment: HI  @Dmitry Bezzubenkov thanks for your reply,I agree with your answer but when i click on edit view1 state should be changed to another how can i do that when i mention the states statically.